# TwilioRestClient for java not working

Tags: java, twilio-api

I have been trying to use the `TwilioRestClient.Builder` class in order to send out an sms using my Twilio number.

I have been using this piece of code within a MessageCreator class:

```
messageCreator = new TwilioMessageCreator(
     newTwilioRestClient.Builder(credentials.getAccountSid(),credentials.getAuthToken())
    .build()
);
```

However, when I use this piece of code in another class, I receive this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/ProtocolVersion com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient$Builder.<init>(TwilioRestClient.java:66)
```

This seems to indicate some problem with the `TwilioRestClient.Builder()` method, but I am unable to identify the issue.

I hope I can get an answer to this!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you are using version 6.x at the moment, the example of `TwilioRestClient.Builder` you are looking at is for version 7.x of the [java library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java).

You can check here how you send messages with version 6.x: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was using Java 8.x and the TwilioRestClient.Builder() class is no longer needed to construct a TwilioRestClient. You can just use TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(twilio_account_sid, twilio_auth_token);